# E: Package 'gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, gdb

I try to install gdb-ARM for cross compile on my ubuntu 14.04 x86 architecture . I want to debug a program on my target with an ARM architecture.I tried this command :

```
sudo apt-get install gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

I got this error :

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Package gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

  E: Package 'gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi' has no installation candidate
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `sudo apt install binutils-mips64el-linux-gnuab` or `sudo apt install gdb-arm-none-eabi`